# Sum dot products and constant in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to do the following calculation in tensorflow

```
Y = X1*W1 + X2*W2 + X3*W3 + b
```

X's and W's have same shape, X*W is dot product.
After playing around for a while I found that the following piece does the job

```
Y = tf.add(tf.add(tf.add(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X1,W1)),tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X2,W2))),tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X3,W3))),b)
```

What is a concise way to perform this operation in tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about defining the dotproduct function?

```
def dotprod(X,W):
  return tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X,W))
Y = dotprod(X1,W1) + dotprod(X2,W2) + dotprod(X3,W3) + b
```

And I believe that you can use the + to add tensors.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Yes, your solution works for me. Yours is a refined approach than mine. What I'm wondering is that since these kind of operations are common in applications of tensorflow, shouldn't there be a built in function for this!

Comment: Yes and no. As you can see here (http://www.pinchofintelligence.com/photorealistic-neural-network-gameboy/) I always define multiple of functions like these to keep my code clean.... If you want to use "higher level" functions you might want to look at Keras. The nice thing about Tensorflow is that it is easy to create these high-level functions, while having the possibility to create other more "creative" ideas.